# Regex don't match specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex, for simplicity let's say it's:

```
([a-z]*[0-9])
```

For the string `aa bbc1 cc` it matches `bbc1`.

Now I want to change the regex in such a way that `c1` is not part of the match anymore. But only if it's c1.

Some examples:
`aa bbb1 cc` will match `bbb1`
`aa bbc1 cc` will match `bb`
`aa bbc2 cc` will match `bbc2`

What I tried:
Negative lookbehind:

```
([a-z]*[0-9])(?<!c1)
```

will not provide `bb` anymore with `aa bbc1 cc`

Negative lookforward:

```
(?!c1)([a-z]*[0-9])
```

Does not seem to make a difference

I'm using javascript.

Comment: *"will not provide `aa` anymore"*: why should it? You have a requirement in your regex that the match should end with a digit...

Comment: Your second example seems ambiguous.  I think you meant that `aa bbc1 dd` will match `bb`, is that right?

Comment: What should happen with `aac12`?

Comment: @Wyck, that is right. Edited the question.

Comment: If from `bbc1` you want to match `bb`, then shouldn't that `1` be a second match?

Comment: @trincot Stackoverflow wants me to note what I have tried, even if it did not work. To me it was not directly obvious why. As for your second comment I expect it to match `aa` as the 2 was never part of the regex to begin with.

Comment: Well `([a-z]*[0-9])` *does* match `2`, so why not?

Comment: Should `2ac1` match `2` or `a` or neither or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
\b[a-z]*?(?:(?=c1)|\d)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SMf4ZW/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `[a-z]*?`: Match 0 or more lowercase letters. Match is non-greedy (lazy) due to use of `*?`
- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `(?=c1)`: Lookahead to assert that we have `c1` immediately ahead of the current position
  - `|`: OR
  - `\d`: Match a digit
- `)`: End non-capture group

PS: If you want your words to end with these combinations then I would suggest:

```bash
\b[a-z]*?(?:(?=c1\b)|\d\b)
```

Comment: It sounds like you understood what I wanted, but clicking your demo match2 still has `aac1` instead of the expected `aa`. In fact, it does not produce a (much) different result from the regex I started with.

Comment: Please try my updated demo link and updated regex

Comment: Thanks. This works. Also thanks for the explanation, it helps understanding this for the next time I have a problem like this.